# Field data disappears in Django REST framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a field "plugins" (see below) in my serializer and this is a serializer which also contains a file upload which is why the `MultiPartParser` is used. My view is pretty much standard, and the `plugins` field data also shows up in the `request.data`, however it doesn't show up in the validated_data of the serializer. To bring a minimalistic example, this would be my serializer:

```
class CreationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer, FileUploadSerializer):
    plugins = serializers.ListSerializer(
        child=serializers.CharField(), required=False, write_only=True)

    class Meta:
        fields = ['plugins'] + FileUploadSerializer.Meta.fields
        model = Company

    def create(self, validated_data):
        print(validated_data)
```

While this would be my views.py:

```
@swagger_auto_schema(request_body=CreationSerializer(), responses={201: CreationSerializer()}, operation_id='the_post')
def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    print(request.data)
    return super().create(request, *args, **kwargs) # which uses mixins.CreateModelMixin
```

I tried adding another parser (i.e. JSONParser) to the parsers list, but this doesn't change anything.

Comment: What is your input data eg. from js API ? Do you provide some array for `plugins` field ?

Comment: Yes, I use a Swagger UI, as this is a purely backend focused application and I provide the plugins as follows: `-H  "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -F "plugins=teststring"` (this is from the curl command)

Comment: plugins field should be [array]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it work if you replace with this? I'm not sure but maybe drf doesn't recognize ListSerializer as a field, I've always used a Serializer with `many=True`:

```py
plugins = serializers.ListField(child=serializers.CharField(), required=False, write_only=True)
```

Comment: Wow, that was actually it! Thank you very much!